# スタックオーバーフローの、デフォルトユーザ画像はどのように生成しているのでしょうか？

Tags: 画像

スタックオーバーフローで、(何も画像をアップロードしていない時点の)デフォルトユーザ画像は、どのように生成しているのでしょうか？

一人ひとり違うよう自動生成しているようにも見えるのですが、その方法を知りたいです

Comment: [How is the default user avatar generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metaにまさにその質問があります。

[How is the default user avatar generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)

このような画像はIdenticonと呼ばれていて、メールアドレスのハッシュ値としてランダムな値を得て画像を生成しているようです。厳密なアルゴリズムまではよくわかりませんが、オリジナルは[こちら](https://github.com/donpark/identicon)で、他にも[PHPの実装](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_identicon/)などが紹介されています。[英語版のWikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)も参考になります。